# Python how to open din files from pysftp connection

Tags: python, pandas, pysftp

I am looping though a list of .din files. I am attempting to open the file and loop through each line but it seems that when I get the files they are only coming in as a string and not an object.

I would like to be able to open a file that I look for but my experience with pystfp is very limited. Any help would go a long way. Thanks.

```
def find_ftp(username, password, cnopts, fileTitle, host):
    host = host
    with pysftp.Connection(host, username=username, password=password, 
                                                 cnopts=cnopts) as sftp:
        filelist = sftp.listdir('/output')
        for filename in filelist:
            print(filename)
            if filename == fileTitle:
                with open(filename) as f:
                    content = f.readlines()
                print("success")
            else:
                print("failure")
```

Answer (score 1):

The mistake in your script is that you are using the built-in function 'open()', which means you are trying to open the path locally instead of remotely on the host. Instead use pysftp.connection.open() which opens the file on the remote host you have established a connection with.

In your code, your 'pysftp.connection' object is called 'sftp'. Note how I have replaced 'open()' with sftp.open()

```
def find_ftp(username, password, cnopts, fileTitle, host):
    host = host
    with pysftp.Connection(host, username=username, password=password, 
                                                 cnopts=cnopts) as sftp:
        filelist = sftp.listdir('/output')
        for filename in filelist:
            print(filename)
            if filename == fileTitle:
                with sftp.open(filename) as f:
                    # Data from SSH is binary, we need to decode to string
                    content = [line.decode("utf-8") for line in f.readlines()]
                print("success")
            else:
                print("failure")
```

Here's some info on the SFTP.connection.open function:
https://paramiko-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/sftp.html?highlight=open#paramiko.sftp_client.SFTPClient.open
( linked from https://pysftp.readthedocs.io/en/release_0.2.8/pysftp.html )